# Getting Selenium Error - selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I'm getting this error in Selenium when trying to automate registration on a page and I can't figure out how to interact with this button. I can inspect it, find it's XPATH, click it, but I can't get Selenium to do it. I'm able to interact with everything else in the page so far except for this.

```
button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="mobile-title-bar"]/div/button').click()  # click save button
```

This is the code I'm using and I've also tried using ActionChains but run into the same problem. I'm assuming because the button is in an overlay (see screenshot) but can't get it for some reason. What am I missing here?
Edit: I can't share the website URL, it's a service behind a paywall.

Picture of Page with HTML Elements:

[image]

Full Error Text:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\PycharmProjects\Albert_new_user\main.py", line 45, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="mobile-title-bar"]/div/button').click()  # click save button
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\PycharmProjects\Albert_new_user\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 89, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\PycharmProjects\Albert_new_user\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 773, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\PycharmProjects\Albert_new_user\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\PycharmProjects\Albert_new_user\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x008CD953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x0085F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x0074C580+836992]
    Ordinal0 [0x0077A4F3+1025267]
    Ordinal0 [0x00770293+983699]
    Ordinal0 [0x0079449C+1131676]
    Ordinal0 [0x0076FC74+982132]
    Ordinal0 [0x007946B4+1132212]
    Ordinal0 [0x007A4812+1198098]
    Ordinal0 [0x007942B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x0076E860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x0076F756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B3CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B2F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00865F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x0086A898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x0086A985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x00873AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76B2FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F57A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppCo
```

ntainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F57A4E+238]

Comment: try doing driver.switch_to.default_content() before clicking Save button

Comment: i dont see any frame in DOM but still try doing switch to driver.switch_to.frame(0)  i am one of these should work

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could add url for this page so we could test it.

Comment: @furas, added the error in the body of the question, thanks for the tip. I can't link to the page because it's a paid service with a login. That's why I posted a ss of the HTML to see if I was missing anything obvious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure but `button` is without `<form>` which normally define where to send request after pressing button - and it can make it unclicable. OR maybe it use some JavaScript code to block access when it detect Selenium. You may try to use JavaScript to click it. Soemthing like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)`

Comment: @SonaliDas, can you explain the driver.switch_to.default_content()?  I created my button variable, ran that command, and then clicked the button but still got the same error back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer that worked from @furas in the comments

I'm not sure but button is without  which normally define where to send request after pressing button - and it can make it unclicable. OR maybe it use some JavaScript code to block access when it detect Selenium. You may try to use JavaScript to click it. Soemthing like

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)`

-furas

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath to click SAVE button

```
//button[contains(text(),'SAVE')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Same error message

Comment: pls share web site url here to check more